# Tool for prototyping TypeScript types faster

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there an online tool, IDE or VSCode settings option/extension that allows to prototype type definitions (easier/faster)?

The only option I am aware of is to hover over a typed statement which displays the associated type in a tooltip. It's very impractical to use as the types are trimmed and non-interactive, i.e. I cannot hover over a type sub-component to see the trimmed part. Also it's impossible to say which sub-type failed as it's not highlighted.
[image: vscode type hint displayed in a tooltip]

If I need to step through a complex type to discover the error, I have to deconstruct it like below and then keep hovering over each statement, which is very inconvenient. Maybe if only the IDE could generate those "result comments" automatically, that would make life easier.
[image: lots of small test type statements]

Comment: Btw, ignore the syntax typo in the screenshot :), the idea of the question remains the same, even though the highlighted error is a result of missing comma.

Comment: Oh, I would love such a tool, if anyone decides to build it, I would be happy to pitch in on the compile API side 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Haha, I hoped you would answer my question, not to join me  https://i.imgur.com/ICqZfZS.jpg